# Cant have both wireless and wired connections enabled at the same time

Tags: networking, 14.10

I have installed Ubuntu 14.10 recently and I have a problem with accessing my storage server via eth0 and connecting to Internet via wlan at the same time. I have to disconnect one of them to use the other one.
my configs for eth0 are:

```
IP: 192.168.2.101
sub: 255.255.255.0
DG: 192.168.2.1
```

and for wlan:

```
ip: 192.168.1.109
sub:255.255.255.0
dg: 192.168.1.1
```

I also tried DHCP in all possible ways.

Link to screenshots with wifi on/off : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vn4Qn.jpg

Comment: Explain what you have done so far. What 'I tried DHCP in all possible ways' means. look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/263572/can-i-use-wifi-and-cable-ethernet-networking-at-same-time

Comment: I tried eth0 DHCP + wlan static and i tried eth0 static + wlan DHCP. And also tried Both of them with DHCP.

Comment: That is because you've two different gateways hanging on both the adapters. How would your PC know which gateway to use when sending such requests? You'll have to add more in detail as to why you've two different network ranges. On a related note, you'll have to add static routing so that you PC will look into those routing when required accordingly.

Comment: @AzkerM yeah sorry. the problem is that i have a printing company downstairs which the network there, is no connected to the internet due to company policies. When i'm in the printing floor i use my laptop to access the storage server of the company and at the same time i access the internet through WiFi of the top floor which is the store! before switching to Ubuntu, i used these exact static IPs in windows and everything worked fine. But now!